# How to modify the Job Region for Dataflow Template Batch processing using gcloud command line?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Recently I encountered the issue, ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED, when running dataflow jobs from a template. So as a solution I plan to update its job region. I used Cloud Scheduler to run Dataflow Jobs using a classic template. What I tried so far is to modify the job region using the body parameters to be set to trigger Dataflow jobs in Cloud Scheduler which goes something like this:

```
  "jobName": "jobName",
  "parameters": {
    "region": "us-east1",
    "autoscalingAlgorithm": "THROUGHPUT_BASED",
  },
  "environment": {
    "maxWorkers": "10",
    "tempLocation": "gs://tempLocation/temp",
    "zone": "us-east1-b"
  }
}
```

But it still keeps using the default job region (us-central1) that has the zone resource issue. Is there any easy way to modify the template's job region aside from creating it again? Perhaps using the gcloud command line?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for this? I'm trying to import CSV files to cloud spanner using the Text Files on Cloud Storage to Cloud Spanner template and hitting the same error repeatedly in us-central1 and northamerica-northeast1.

Comment: hello @randomdatascientist if you've set up a cloud scheduler configuration using the UI you have to modify the body and URL (My trigger type is http). For the body, just do the same format as shown above but modify the parameters to another region or zone. Modify the Url with something like this "https: //dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/<project-id>/locations/<region>/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://path/to/template" The region you specified in the URL should be the same as the one you set in the body parameter. The gcs folder where you stored the template must be multi-regional

Comment: Hi yes that is the default region for my project. I ended up moving the job to south Carolina and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think 'us-central1' is the fallback region in cases when no region is given. Are you sure your Dataflow Job config, created by Cloud Scheduler, is correct?

Starting your classic template using gcloud (e.g., in the cloud shell on the GCP console or with the SDK on your local machine), as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates#example-1:-custom-template,-batch-job), with another region as the one specified when creating the template, worked for me:

```
 gcloud dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME \
     --region us-east1
     --gcs-location gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/templates/MyTemplate \
     --parameters inputFile=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/input/my_input.txt,outputFile=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/output/my_output
```